# Strategy for dynamically generating directives. Logic in compile, link, or controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to create a sidebar that will be generated based on data received from the back-end, which will be an array of items. Basically, each piece of data I receive will be its own component, but all together, they will form the side bar. The data I receive will not always be the same depending on the page, but the possible items will be known. So it's not like it's random data. I'll have a directive for each item.

I was thinking that I'd create a container directive (the sidebar) and create a directive for each smaller component. On the page load, the sidebar container would have some logic that knows how to bind the back-end item to the associated directive. It would just iterate through the items, find it's proper directive, then compile and append it to the sidebar element.

Does that sound like the correct approach? For that logic that involves mapping the back-end item to a directive, where should that go? Should that go in the compile, link, or controller function? I would have thought to use the controller function and utilize `$element` and `$compile`, but wanted to check on the input of others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try out something and post the code if you get stuck.